# Merged DataFrame by checking if values exists in list of another Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, list, merge

I have a 2 DF that looks like below:

DF1

```
time     id
15-06    1
16-06    3
17-06    5
18-06    7
```

DF2:

```
result  idx
'asd'   [18,3]
'qwe'   [20,5]
'zxc'   [7]
'ty'    [987,9]
'qwe'   [1000]
```

Output should be like this:

```
time     id  result idx
15-06    1   NaN    NaN
16-06    3   'asd'  [18,3]
17-06    5   'qwe'  [20,5]
18-06    7   'zxc'  [7]
```

So I tried to make a left merge like below but it doesn't take into account values in list

```
df1.merge(df2, how="left", left_on = "id", right_on="idx")
```

Then I try to assigned data but there was an issue with lenngth of table (there were not the same)

```
df3 = df.assign(id=[[s.get(y) for y in x if y in s] for x in df2['idx']])
```

Do you have any idea how I can solve it? Thanks for help

Regards
Tomasz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with new column `id` by column `idx` with left join:

```
df = DF1.merge(DF2.assign(id = DF2.idx).explode('id'), how="left", on = "id")
print (df)
    time id result      idx
0  15-06  1    NaN      NaN
1  16-06  3  'asd'  [18, 3]
2  17-06  5  'qwe'  [20, 5]
3  18-06  7  'zxc'      [7]
```